# Output prints inside else statement when it's not supposed to

Tags: c++

So I am having issues with the order of everything printing out. It should be "Do you have a discount coupon?" Then "Is the discount for an adult or child's ticket?" Then based on the answer either an error code or proceeding to the receipt. Discount should only pop up if the user had a Y answer in the "Do you have a discount coupon?" section. But I can't make it work with the if and else statements.

At first I tried to have all the if and else statements together, but the order in which things printed wasn't right. So now I tried inserting the receipt in the middle but that's messing with the if statement's operation and it doesn't print right. Regardless if I enter C or A (which are both characters declared later on and should not prompt the error message to print) the error message prints. The discount still applies but the error message should not print.

```
cout<< "\nDo you have a discount coupon (Y for yes)? ";                             
cin>> haveDiscount;

if (haveDiscount == "Y")
{
    cout<< "\nIs the discount for an adult or child's ticket (A for adult, C for child)? ";
    cin>> discountType;
}
if (haveDiscount == "N")
{
    cout<< endl;
}
else
{
    cout<< "\nError: ";
    cout<< discountType;
    cout<<" is not a valid discount type. No discount will be applied.";
}

cout<< "\n\n************************************" << endl;
cout<< right << setw(22) << "Theater Sale";
cout<< "\n************************************";                                            
cout<< "\n\nNumber of adult tickets: " << setw(11) << adultTickets;                         
cout<< "\nNumber of child tickets: " << setw(11) << childTickets << endl;

if (discountType == "A")
{
    coupon = 11.25;
    cout<< "\nDiscount: " << setw(26) << coupon << endl;
}
else
{
    if (discountType == "C")
    {
        coupon = 4.50;
        cout<< "\nDiscount: " << setw(26) << coupon << endl;
    }
}

total = (adultPrice * adultTickets) + (childPrice * childTickets) - coupon;
cout<< "\nTotal purchase: " << setw(20) << total;
```

I need the error message to not print when I enter C or A (these are declared for the discounts), and only print in any other cases.

Comment: I'd start by indenting your code. Without that, following the logic of the if/then/else statements is next to impossible. As soon as I indented it, some logic problems nearly jumped out.

Comment: Show how `haveDiscount` and `discountType` are declared.

Comment: just as a string so string haveDiscount, discountType;
also, I do have it indented in my actual code, it was just not copying well from there for some reason so I had to take those out

Comment: Is it a `std::string` or a  c-string / char array?

Comment: Looks like you could be leaving `discountType` improperly set, but it's hard to say without better context.

Comment: std::string and it does work when I have all the if/else statements together no problem, it's just that I have to have certain things printed in certain order, that's why I had to change it and started having problems.

Comment: When `haveDiscount == "Y"` is true then `haveDiscount == "N"` will always be false causing the else to execute.  Why is you error about the discount type when you haven't check that variable?

Comment: You may also want to look for if...else if... else...

Answer (score 0):

If you indent your code it's a lot easier to read. It looks like you're missing a couple ifs and elses.
It looks like this right now:

```
if (haveDiscount == "Y") 
{
   // ask next question
}
if (haveDiscount == "N") 
{
   // print new line
} 
else 
{
   // print error
}
```

Which means no matter what if they have a discount it will print the error. It's printing the error if haveDiscount does not equal "N" - which will always be true if they answered "Y" for the first question.
You probably want something more like this:

```
if (haveDiscount == "Y") 
{
   // ask next question
   if (discountType == "C" || discountType == "A")
   {
      // do something
   }
   else 
   {
      // print error
   }
}
else 
{
   // print new line
}
```

Comment: I do have discountType C and A declared on the bottom because the discount amount has to print out only when those are selected but after the number of child tickets. And the error message has to print out right after "Is the discount for an adult or child's ticket?" This is where my problem is, the order in which these have to print out.

Comment: Yes, it should still have the error right after the way I have it here.

Answer (score 0):

To print your error when `discountType` is not C or A could look like

```
if (discountType == "A") 
{
    coupon = 11.25; cout<< "\nDiscount: " << setw(26) << coupon << endl; 
}
else if (discountType == "C")
{
    coupon = 4.50; cout<< "\nDiscount: " << setw(26) << coupon << endl;
}
else
{
    cout<< "\nError: ";
    cout<< discountType;
    cout<<" is not a valid discount type. No discount will be applied."; }
}
```

If you want the error to print before the receipt, then you could do

```
if (discountType != "C" || discountType != "A")
{
    // Error message
}
```

Somewhere after `discountType` has been set.